# How to create a subgrid on one Form and pass its values to a look up in another form

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, subgrid

Hi i am a completely new to crm2011 and I'm really stuck on with this -

I have created a Candidate form with FirstName, LastName and a look up that will display his college details.

I have also created a Form named College with fields - College name and Address and below i have created a subgrid.

I want the below subgrid to show lists of registered candidates from Candidates Entity

Now onload of College form i will enter college details and choose one or more candidate from the subgrid and on click of create the college details should be assigned automatically to the look up in Candidates Form.

What i have done is-

- Created the College Form  and created a subgrid on the same page associated it with the Candidates entity
- Created the Candidate Form and created a lookup on Candidate Form 
  and associated it with the College Entity

But beyond this i am not understanding how shall i go about it.  Also the Subgrid is not showing candidates data in the grid onload

Please if anyone can help me kick start with this.

Answer (score 0):

A SubGird associated with candidates will only show candidates that are already connected to collage.
When you create a new collage it does not exist yet so you can’t associate candidates with it anyway.

What you’re trying to do can only be accomplished via plug-in (server side code) and some JS that collects the selected candidates from a General SubGrid 
That enlists all candidates.  The JS should drill in to get selected candidates and save there guids (ids) in some arbitrary text field to be used in the plug-in.

Once candidates are related to this newly created collage you can see the association in the associated view on the navigation pane.

The easier way is to do it the way CRM intended it to be, which is to firstly create the collage record and then go to its associated candidates view and add them.

Good Luck